# How-to remove rows from array with missing columns

Tags: php, arrays, filter

Ok... So, i have a system that provides me with a array of items. These items are shown like this:

```
Array
(
    [1] => Array
        (
            [protocol] => ip
            [dst-address] => 10.0.0.1
            [tx] => 0
            [rx] => 0
            [tx-packets] => 0
            [rx-packets] => 0
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [protocol] => ip
            [dst-address] => 10.0.0.112
            [tx] => 0
            [rx] => 0
            [tx-packets] => 0
            [rx-packets] => 0
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [protocol] => ip
            [dst-address] => 10.0.0.130
            [tx] => 0
            [rx] => 0
            [tx-packets] => 0
            [rx-packets] => 0
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [tx] => 0
            [rx] => 0
            [tx-packets] => 0
            [rx-packets] => 0
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [protocol] => ip
            [dst-address] => 10.0.0.5
            [tx] => 0
            [rx] => 496
            [tx-packets] => 0
            [rx-packets] => 1
        )

    [6] => Array
        (
            [protocol] => ip
            [dst-address] => 10.0.0.6
            [tx] => 0
            [rx] => 528
            [tx-packets] => 0
            [rx-packets] => 1
        )

    [7] => Array
        (
            [protocol] => ip
            [dst-address] => 10.0.0.16
            [tx] => 624
            [rx] => 0
            [tx-packets] => 1
            [rx-packets] => 0
        )

    [8] => Array
        (
            [protocol] => ip
            [dst-address] => 10.0.0.24
            [tx] => 0
            [rx] => 448
            [tx-packets] => 0
            [rx-packets] => 1
        )

    [9] => Array
        (
            [protocol] => ip
            [dst-address] => 10.0.0.31
            [tx] => 0
            [rx] => 528
            [tx-packets] => 0
            [rx-packets] => 1
        )

    [10] => Array
        (
            [protocol] => ip
            [dst-address] => 10.0.0.44
            [tx] => 10592
            [rx] => 13200
            [tx-packets] => 20
            [rx-packets] => 28
        )
```

Has you see, the entry ID 4 miss some columns on the table.

In PHP, how can i remove the wrongly rows from the array?
I want to get the array correctly fixed in order to re-order it to show things like: 
- top tx
- top rx
- top tx-packets
- top rx packets
- What is the dst-address that have the most tx or rx or tx-packets or rx-packets.

For info, this array is dinamic. My PHP code will fetch it from the device (a router) on a while(true) loop (no data storage).

Comment: You are expected to try to **write the code yourself**. After [**doing more research**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/1011527) if you have a problem **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and provide [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) a good question. Be sure to [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/347937/1011527).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$arrayVar = []; // Replace with your outter array;
$correctCount = 6;
$index = 0;
foreach($arrayVar as $subArray) {
  if(count($subArray) !== $correctCount) {
    unset($arrayVar[$index];
  }
  $index++;
}
```

This loops through the array, counts that the sub arrays have the correct number of items, and if not, removes them. The index increments by 1 at each pass so we know where to remove the improper sub array.

You can change the count to whatever the correct number of items is.

Comment: This is exactly what i was looking for. It solved my problem. Thanks.